# wireshark search tcp stream for string

Tags: search, tcp, filter, stream, wireshark

I need to be able to search all tcp streams that contain a particular string, not just a particular packet. Something like:

tcp.stream contains "string"

I need to do this in order to filter out all streams containing a certain string to get exactly what I'm looking for. My end goal filter would look something like this:

!(tcp.stream contains "string I do not want")

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

**Option 1 - Display Filter:**

Try the following display filter `tcp and frame contains "xxxxxx"`

**Option 2 - Ctrl+F:**

1. Find (Ctrl +F)
2. Find by String
3. Search in packet Bytes